# Why do I get a 'cannot call a method on a null-valued expression' error?

Tags: powershell, smtp

I want to send an email using powershell and it's working perfectly
but when I try adding attachment its giving me an error.
This is the code

```
$SMTPClient.Send($EmailFrom, $EmailTo, $Subject, $Body)
$SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("example@gmail.com", "$$$$$$");
$SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $true
$SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, 587)
$attachment = "$env:appdata\Microsoft\dump\dump.zip"
$attach = new-object Net.Mail.Attachment($attachment)
$message.Attachments.Add($attach)
$SMTPServer = "smtp.gmail.com"
$Body = "Tricknology Test"
$Subject = "Test"
```

and this is the error

````
At line:4 char:1
+ $message.Attachments.Add($attach)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull```
````

Comment: The order of things is totally wrong.. You need to start your script by defining the `$SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, 587)` first. Then set the properties to that object and as last line in the code you send the email.

Comment: Probably also put "$SMTPServer" definition at the start, at the first line.

Comment: i edited it now there is another error


Exception calling "Send" with "1" argument(s): "The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not
authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first.
e12-20020a056000178c00b0020aaf8d351bsm1013966wrg.103 - gsmtp


i got less secure option enabled and started ttls at first too it's working some time and som time it doesn't

Comment: You haven't edited anything as far as we can see.. Your code still tries to send an email using an **undefined** `$SMTPClient` variable at that point. Try to think about the logic. PowerShell reads and executes top to bottom.

Answer (score 0):

As commented, you need to get the order of things right.
PowerShell reads and executes code from top to bottom and in your case, you are trying to perform the `.Send()` method on a variable that hasn't been defined yet..

You are also using a `$message` variable that has not been defined anywhere in the code.

Try

```
# step 1: create the object
$SMTPServer = 'smtp.gmail.com'
$SMTPClient = New-Object System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SMTPServer, 587)

# step 2: set the object's properties
$SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential('example@gmail.com', '$$$$$$')
$SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $true

# step 3: create an attachment object and set it to your file
$attachment = Join-Path -Path $env:APPDATA -ChildPath 'Microsoft\dump\dump.zip'
$attach     = New-Object System.Net.Mail.Attachment($attachment)

# step 4: create a Message object and add the attachment to it
$EmailFrom = 'you@gmail.com'
$EmailTo   = 'someone@somewhere.com'
$Body      = 'Tricknology Test'
$Subject   = 'Test'
$message   = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage($EmailFrom, $EmailTo, $Subject, $Body)
$message.Attachments.Add($attach)

# step finally: send the email and clean up
$SMTPClient.Send($message)
$attach.Dispose()
$message.Dispose()
$SMTPClient.Dispose()
```